# Angular5 nested JSON to Excel convertion

Tags: json, excel, angular5

We are developing an Angular5 application. we have to integrate report (JSON to Excel) exporting option in the application, we have tried **[this plug-in](https://github.com/luwojtaszek/ngx-excel-export)** for that, simple JSON structure is working fine. When we are trying nested array/ dictionary its not working correctly.

Sample code below

```
` let  arrayJson = [
            {id: 1, name: 'a',test:[{test123:'dsdsdsd mmmmmmmm'}]},
            {id: 2, name: 'b',test:[{test123:'dsdsdsd bbbbbbbbb'}]},
            {id: 3, name: 'c',test:[{test123:'dsdsdsd nnnnnnnnnn'}]}
         ];`
```

Result we are getting:

```
 `1, a,object`
```

How can we generate nested JSON for export to Excel?

Comment: So you want to generate JSON to import into Excel? It's doable but I wouldn't recommend it. If you need data in Excel, why not create an Excel file instead of a JSON file? (Or if you need the JSON too then generate both.)

Comment: JSON we get from Rest API and will display in the application, Excel is for user to download as file,  for further analysis.